# AppArmor killing TOR in Mint18

Tags: tor, linux-mint, apparmor

I'm setting up a new install of Mint 18 Cinnamon. Neither the default Ubuntu TOR or the TORs own repo version will work. Both fail with:

```
tor@default.service: Failed at step APPARMOR spawning /usr/bin/tor: No such file or directory
Feb 11 20:22:57 bruce kernel: [  271.946658] audit: type=1400 audit(1486844577.625:12): apparmor="DENIED" operation="change_onexec" info="label not found" error=-2 profile="unconfined" name="system_tor" pid=5079 comm="(tor)"
```

in syslog. But /usr/bin/tor does exist:

```
$ ls /usr/bin/tor  -l
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2278112 Mar 22  2016 /usr/bin/tor
```

Running /etc/init.d/tor start does the same. But weirdly, running sudo /usr/bin/tor does work! O'course that's a really bad way to do it...

There's nothing at all in /var/log/tor

Any ideas? I've never had to deal with AppArmor before, it's always just worked, and Google gets me nowhere.

Comment: You can disable apparmor (many devs do this to not deal with it's draconian lock down policies) or you can try to add a rule to app armor to allow tor to execute as its proper user. I would google either of those things and try something, then come back here when _that_ is not working

Answer (score 0):

There already is a bug entry here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apparmor/+bug/1648143

Someone said that it was fixed, so maybe a kernel update could help.